# Using xcape + xmodmap to change some keys

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xcape

Using [`xcape`](https://github.com/alols/xcape) and [`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap), how does one

1. Make the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key behave as a <kbd>SUPER</kbd> modifier key when pressed in conjunction w/another key.
2. Make the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key function as the <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> key when pressed on its own.

Comment: Is it important to use only xcape and xmodmap, and not xkb?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the following sequence: press CapsLock, press A, release A, release CapsLock? Do you want to wait until CapsLock is released to generate an Escape event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Configure <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>Super</kbd>

These lines to configure <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>SUPER</kbd>

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Super_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

Add them to `~/.xmodmap` using your favorite  text editor `vi/gedit`:

```
$ gedit ~/.xmodmap
```

Now run

```
$ xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

Now the new <kbd>Super</kbd> key is ready to be used.

### 2. Use `xcape` to add a new layer to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> when held

Now use `xcape` command to configure <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> when pressed alone

```
$ xcape -e 'Super_L=Escape'
```

For more options, use:

```
$ xcape -e 'Super_L=Escape' -t 300
```

If you hold <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> longer than 300ms, `xcape` will not generate a <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Change it if you like, the default is 500ms.

### 3. Automating the Setup

Run them in this order — for example in your start-up script, e.g. `.xinitrc` —:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
xcape -e 'Super_L=Escape'
```

Comment: What is the point of removing and then adding `lock`?