# Bind CAPS+hjkl to arrow keys; CAPS to ESC

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Currently running Antergos Linux. The set-up I would like to have is the following.

1. Pressing and releasing CAPS sends ESC.
2. The combinations of CAPS and any of CAPS+h, CAPS+j, CAPS+k, CAPS+l send Left, Down, Up, and Right respectively. Upon release of CAPS, ESC is not sent.

Of course, the goal here is to get some VIM-style bindings in programs which do not have them.

It seems that xcape would be useful here:

https://github.com/alols/xcape

But the examples do not get me quite as far as I would like.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I came across a very useful answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163675/267068

Can anybody help me figure how to modify the procedure so that I get CAPS+hjkl as needed. Could I use Hyper_L, instead of the Super_L in that answer, and then map Hyper_L + hjkl to left, down, up, right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wanted to do the exact same thing, and after some search and experiment, finally got it working.

### Solution 1

*See solution 2 below, which is potentially better.*

1. Mapping <kbd>Caps_lock</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>:

   Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/898462) and add the config. You should add to the `us` file if you are using the US keyboard layout and skip the other keybindings that you're not interested in. Then run `setxkbmap -layout us`.
2. <kbd>Caps_lock</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

   Run `xcape -e 'ISO_Level3_Shift=Escape'`. You can add this line to your `/etc/profile` so you don't have to run it manually after reboot.

### Solution 2 (probably better)

I was happy with solution 1, until I realized I couldn't use the key bindings in IntelliJ, which is a big bummer. Eventually I figured out that I could just use `xmodmap` and `xcape` to do the job, while still being able to use them in IntelliJ!

1. Mapping <kbd>Caps_lock</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>:

   Create a file (say `~/.xmodmap`) with the following content:

   ```
   keycode 66 = Mode_switch
   keysym h = h H Left
   keysym l = l L Right
   keysym k = k K Up
   keysym j = j J Down
   keysym u = u U Prior
   keysym i = i I Home
   keysym o = o O End
   keysym p = p P Next
   ```

   Feel free to skip the last 4 lines. I pasted them because they might be useful to you as well. In fact I'm really hoping to get the [caps_lock enhancement](https://github.com/Vonng/Capslock) working in Linux.

   Then, run `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap`.
2. <kbd>Caps_lock</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

   Run `xcape -e 'Mode_switch=Escape'`.
3. Optional:

   To avoid manually applying the keybindings, put the above 2 commands into your `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Many thanks! Sorry for not responding sooner. I was off-grid for some time. However, with Solution 2, I get the following error when I run xcape: "No keycode found for keysym Escape in mapping Mode_switch."

Comment: My mistake. Forgot to remove some old settings. This is working great. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like solution 2 (step 1) breaks other layouts. It works in English, but when I switch (Win + Space) e.g. to Russian I cannot type letters on these keys and caps + hjkl also doesn't work until I switch back to English.

Comment: Also **shift** + caps + hjkl (text selection) doesn't seem to work in IntelliJ, in other apps it works.

Comment: For those curious about the meaning of the xmodmap configuration file presented in this answer, the [Arch Linux docs on xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) is a good place to read about it.  You don't have to read very much to get a basic understanding of this config file - Just the "Introduction" and "Keymap Table" sections.

Comment: I have developed an interception plugin that works one layer above the kernel. It does not depend on Xorg. For more visit [interception-caps2esc-hjkl-arrow](https://github.com/akarsh1995/interception-caps2esc-hjkl-arrow)

Answer (score 1):

I use 3rd layer symbols and assign arrows to letters `hjkl`

Install `gnome-tweaks` tool

Inside gnome-tweaks go to Additional Layout Options and choose Caps Look as a key to choose the 3rd level.

Then open your terminal and go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` There are all keyboard layouts store on your computer

Make a backup of your layout

`cp us us_old`

Modify file as root

`sudo nano us`

Third values in arrays are your keys:

```
key <AC01> {[a,A,Home]};
key <AC02> {[s,S,BackSpace]};
key <AC03> {[d,D,Delete]};
key <AC04> {[f,F,End]};
key <AC05> {[g,G]};
key <AC06> {[h,H,Left]};
key <AC07> {[j,J,Down]};
key <AC08> {[k,K,Up]};
key <AC09> {[l,L,Right]};
```

Comment: You'll need to press ALT+F2, enter "r" to reload the gnome session or just log out and in again after altering the `symbols/us` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting this to work properly with /etc/profile, so expanding on the answer from @matrinica I was able to achieve success (on ubuntu/gnome) with the following method:

## Step 0 : install xclip and xcape

```
sudo apt install xclip
sudo apt install xcape
```

## Step 1 : create ~/.xmodmap

Copy the following text:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Up
keysym j = j J Down
```

Create file with contents:

```
touch ~/.xmodmap
xclip -o > ~/.xmodmap
```

## Step 2 : create script

Copy the following text:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
xcape -e 'Mode_switch=Escape'
```

Create file with contents:

```
touch ~/xmodmap.sh
xclip -o > ~/xmodmap.sh
```

Make file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/xmodmap.sh
```

## Step 3 : create autostart entry

Copy the following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=sh -c "$HOME/xmodmap.sh"
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=xmodmap
Comment=xmodmap script
```

Create file with contents:

```
touch ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.deskop
xclip -o > ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.deskop
```

### Note:

This method does not work with Wayland and so is not futureproof. For Wayland compatible methods of achieving similar results please consult:

https://askubuntu.com/a/898462

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_input

https://realh.co.uk/wp/linux-keymap-hacking/

If you are able to come up with a clean method which is Wayland compatible please post it here.