# How to select text when Arrows, Home, and End are mapped to Mode_Switch+Letter

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I managed to map the arrow keys, Home, and End to Mode_Switch+Letter (where mode switch is Caps Lock) as explained in this answer:

[Bind CAPS+hjkl to arrow keys; CAPS to ESC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414926/bind-capshjkl-to-arrow-keys-caps-to-esc/434143#434143)

though if I want to select text, for example a full line using Shift+End, I cannot do it when using the combination Shift+Mode_Switch+Letter. Is it there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used [Solution 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414926/bind-capshjkl-to-arrow-keys-caps-to-esc/434143#434143),

following `xmodmap` documentation:

> The first keysym is used when no modifier key is pressed in
>   conjunction with this key, the second with Shift, the third when the
>   Mode_switch key is used with this key and the fourth when both the
>   Mode_switch and Shift keys are used.

add the **fourth** `keysym`:

keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left Left
keysym l = l L Right Right
keysym k = k K Up Up
keysym j = j J Down Down
keysym u = u U Prior Prior
keysym i = i I Home Home
keysym o = o O End End
keysym p = p P Next Next

Comment: It works. Thanks for the answer. Now I just need to figure out how to disable layout switching when Mode_switch is pressed in KDE.